# Load a 16 bit Integer into an existing byte array

Tags: arrays, vb.net, byte

Using Visual Studio Visual Basic

Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019 Version 16.11.27

Microsoft.NET.Framework Version 4.8.04084

Windows 10 64 Bit

I have created a Byte Array and read bytes data from a binary file using:

```
Dim array() As Byte = File.ReadAllBytes(Filename)

Using memory As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream(array)
Using reader As BinaryReader = New BinaryReader(memory)
```

Now I read a 16-bit Integer from the Byte Array:

```
Data_Offset = 1024
Data16 = BitConverter.ToUInt16(array, Data_Offset)
```

Now, I need to modify the value of Data16 and write it back into the array at the same location.

I’m unable to find the correct method to save the new Data16 value to array(Data_Offset)

Any help is greatly appreciated

```
array(1024) = Data16
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try,

```
    Dim MyArray() As Byte = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}
    Dim val As UInt16
    Dim Data_Offset As Integer = 2
    val = BitConverter.ToUInt16(MyArray, Data_Offset)
    val = val + 1023US
    Array.Copy(BitConverter.GetBytes(val), 0, MyArray, Data_Offset, 2)
```

[Array.Copy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.copy?view=netframework-4.8.1)

Comment: What is 1023US?

Comment: US is a type character.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/data-types/type-characters